# Stationary in levels I(0), three variables -- cointegration test?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

After running ADF-tests and kpss-test I find that the variables are stationary without drift and trend. I have two questions:

1. Is it the correct use of terminology to say that they are not integrated, i.e, I(0)? (wich implies that there is no need for cointegration-tests)
2. Since I have three variables, should I do some kind of Johansen test?

Here is the results from one of my variables. Not necessary to the question, but someone might find it useful. Thankful for advice.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tomas. Cointegrated models are only required when your data is non-stationary. You should view a cointegration test as a joint ADF test. The purpose of which is to find a stationary residual among the non-stationary variables. Under such circumstances, your variables are 'co-integrated.' However, if your three variables are already stationary, then you do not need to conduct a cointegration test.

Comment: @EB3112, consider turning your comment into an answer. TomasR, please do not post pictures of your code but rather copy the text and format it as code. (This applies to your previous questions, too.) This is how we do it at Cross Validated.